# Python simple madlibs generator random.randint in while loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the past few days I've been attempting to teach myself Python and CS. This question is fairly basic, but I feel it is important understand where my problem is originating. The program in question is a simple madlibs generator template.

```
import random

name1 = input("Please enter a name.\n")
verb1 = input("Please enter a verb.\n")
noun1 = input("Please enter a noun.\n")
noun2 = input("Please enter another noun.\n")
adjective = input("Please enter an adjective.\n")
verb2 = input("Please enter an verb.\n")
game1_running = False
game2_running = False
game3_running = False
while((game1_running == False) and (game2_running == False) and (game3_running == False)):
    chance = random.randint(1, 3)
    if chance == 1:
        game1_running == True
        break
    if chance == 2:
        game2_running == True
        break
    if chance == 3:
        game3_running == True
        break

while game1_running == True:
    print(name1 + " Game 1 Active" + verb1 + noun1 + noun2 + adjective + verb2)
    game1_running = False
    break
while game2_running == True:
    print(name1 + " Game 2 Active" + verb1 + noun1 + noun2 + adjective + verb2)
    game2_running = False
    break
while game3_running == True:
    print(name1 + "Game 3 Active" + verb1 + noun1 + noun2 + adjective + verb2)
    game3_running = False
    break
```

When I run this program, everything goes smoothly but it does not print out game 1, 2, or 3. I believe this is because the random number is not being detected by the if statements (because i just had a similar problem with a dice simulator). Any suggestions as to improvement or better methods of accomplishing this would be much appreciated, as well as an explanation as to what is happening in my code currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code isn't doing what you want it to is here:

```
if chance == 1:
    game1_running == True
    break
if chance == 2:
    game2_running == True
    break
if chance == 3:
    game3_running == True
    break
```

`==` is used to test for equality, but you want to assign a value, so you should be using `=` instead.

More generally, though, a `while` loop is better used in cases where you potentially want to repeat a set of actions numerous times until some condition is true. If you only want to repeat an action once, using `if`/`else` is more appropriate. The first `while` loop could be eliminated entirely as you have set it up so that it will only execute once.

The main body of your game could thus be rewritten as follows:

```
game1_running = False
game2_running = False
game3_running = False

chance = random.randint(1, 3)

if chance == 1:
    game1_running = True
elif chance == 2:
    game2_running = True
elif chance == 3:
    game3_running = True

if game1_running == True:
    print(name1 + " Game 1 Active" + verb1 + noun1 + noun2 + adjective + verb2)
    game1_running = False
elif game2_running == True:
    print(name1 + " Game 2 Active" + verb1 + noun1 + noun2 + adjective + verb2)
    game2_running = False
elif game3_running == True:
    print(name1 + "Game 3 Active" + verb1 + noun1 + noun2 + adjective + verb2)
    game3_running = False
```

Setting a condition (`gameX_running`) and then testing for it a moment later also represents an unneeded extra step, so you could combine these sets of `if`/`else` conditions:

```
chance = random.randint(1, 3)
if chance == 1:
    print(name1 + " Game 1 Active" + verb1 + noun1 + noun2 + adjective + verb2)
    # do other game 1 runtime stuff here
elif chance == 2:
    print(name1 + " Game 2 Active" + verb1 + noun1 + noun2 + adjective + verb2)
    # game 2 runtime stuff
elif chance == 3:
    print(name1 + "Game 3 Active" + verb1 + noun1 + noun2 + adjective + verb2)
    # game 3 runtime stuff
```

An appropriate use for a `while` loop in a game situation like this might be to execute a number of games in a row, for example:

```
n = 0
while n < 10:
    chance = random.randint(1, 3)

    if chance == 1:
        print(name1 + " Game 1 Active" + verb1 + noun1 + noun2 + adjective + verb2)

    elif chance == 2:
        print(name1 + " Game 2 Active" + verb1 + noun1 + noun2 + adjective + verb2)

    elif chance == 3:
        print(name1 + " Game 3 Active" + verb1 + noun1 + noun2 + adjective + verb2)

    n += 1
```

Comment: Thank you! You adressed everything i needed help with. I appreciate you helping me with such a basic program.

Comment: @user10142179 No problem! If the answer was helpful, please click the tick at the top to accept it. :)